# Logout getting PHP Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm new with PHP and I'm trying to solve this problem but I don't know how.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require "../config.php";
    $retvaloff = mysqli_query($con);
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

> PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in logout.php on line 4

As it says, there is only 1 parameter and it must be 2. Which parameter could I add to `mysqli_query`?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to add the SQL query that you want to execute.

Comment: I strongly recommend to use PDO instead of mysqli. Here is a good tutorial https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send two parameters to mysqli_query:

1. db connection and
2. query.

for [reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

At this moment you only send db connections to this function.

Answer (score 0):

First parameter to the `mysqli_query` function is your connection `resource` (I assume `$con` in your case), second parameter is the query (string).

PS: Make sure to protect against SQL injection.

Comment: Which link about SQL injection would you suggest?

Comment: @JeroenvanderLaan Please do not use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`